# How to breed good kings?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I play France and had quite a few good monarchs (with 4/4/4 Monarch points, 5/3/2), but now my King has 5/1/1 Monarch Points, my heir 1/0/6...

Why did monarchs became so weak? Should I have marriages with STRONG countries?

Comment: As @Richard_ten_Brink suggests and unlike Crusader Kings 2 it is completely random and if your Monarch is an oaf you just have to adjust your playing style accordingly. Become more defensive then aggressive etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry man, it's all random.

I once did a little experiment with it by saving and loading a few times when I was new to the game. I did this by saving right at the end of a regency period where the system generated a new heir immadiatley at the ascension of my new monarch. The new heir could be complete rubbish, quite fantastic or anything in between.

Comment: That sound like non-ironmode-gamer should consider 'reload' option to breed the king? khm. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is always interesting to find out how stuff works. After that Iron Man is the only way to go when playing vs AI only.

Answer (score 0):

Play a republic. That's about it. They get a character with a 4 and 2 1s depending on which stat you want to be the highest, and re-electing them gives +1 to all stats and 50 MP of a random catagory, though hurts your republican tradition, so you don't want to re-elect too much, especially if the guy is old and will probably die soon after the election anyway.

For everyone else it's completely random.